# How to remove crop or limit marks from Icons or logos in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

Here I  have an image from google, they provide it in png format with some limit or crop marks. My question is-
How to remove that inside flutter without external image editing? Is there any crop feature inside the flutter?
I have also tried the image viewer inside the android studio that provides something like a safe area but it doesn't do anything. Please help me with this.

please find the images below- [image: Cropmarks in app icon]
[image: the safe area zone inside Android studio]
[image: original image with crop marks]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using picture in the assets the easiest way in windows is using paint and crop the picture there and send it again in android studio

Comment: yes, thank-you, but I was not looking for an external option, as google shares images in that format (officially ) then there should be some way to cut or crop those things in flutter.